# How to get last process of async forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I might be messing up things in the async hell I am currently in and would gladly take any help after debugging for half a day now.

The task is to asynchronously update a bunch of entities in the database. It is:

1. Gets a list of entities of type Foo
2. for each of these elements update it in the database
3. SELECT entities of type Bar with corresponding conditions and update them accordingly
4. After all updates return an array of objects of the form `[{entity: 'Foo || Bar', id: foo.id || bar.id}]`

What I currently have is the following (with Bluebird Promise.map):

```
exports.updateFooAndBars = function (req, res) {
  var arrayOfFoos = req.body;
  var projectId = req.params.projectId;
  var result = [];
  Promise.map(arrayOfFoos, function(foo, index){
    var fooId = foo.id;
    fooLib.update(foo, fooId)
    .then(function (updatedFoo){
      return barLib.update(foo, projectId);
    });
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // handles PUT responses
    updated(res, result);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
      .....
  )};
```

This of course does not work since the last .then-block is invoked before the others are done.

But I can't find out where and how I can jump in to process the response to the client exactly after **every update has been finished**? The index I am getting in `Promise.map(arrayOfFoos, function(foo, index)` is totally messing up during the processing such that I seem to not be able to rely on it for sending the response when index is equal to arrayOfFoos.length.

And since there might be quite plenty of entities which will be updated in this process, I do not want to this synchronously as far as I can avoid that to not block the backend during the process.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Vegaaaa

Comment: You need to `return` the promise from the callback function so that `map` can wait for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning the Promise chain created by `fooLib.update()`. Your `Promise.map()` is iterating through all the items in the array, invoking the callback and continuing to the `.then()` on your `Promise.map()`  immediately instead of waiting for all of the Promise chains created from each of the `fooLib.update()` calls.

When working with Promises, if there is any internal Promise created, you need to return each of those to ensure the Promise chain is fully awaited for all asynchronous work, if that is something your code requires.

```
Promise.map(arrayOfFoos, function(foo, index){
  var fooId = foo.id;
  return fooLib.update(foo, fooId)
    .then(function (updatedFoo){
      return barLib.update(foo, projectId);
    });
  })
```

Comment: Actually you need to return the `fooLib.update().then()` promise, not just the `fooLib.update()` promise.

Comment: @Bergi I've updated my answer to say, the promise chain created by `fooLib.update()` needs to be returned.

Comment: I am pretty sure this was the first thing I did, since I am used to return my promises, but I than somehow never reached the .then block of the Promise.map(). But I might mix up things after starring on this for 4 hours straight. Gonna check it out tomorrow, I went home now.

Comment: This was the hint! I did that before and I actually never reached the then-block of the Promise.map with that solution. However, I implemented a little test code with the exact structure and it worked fine. So I started debugging the original code and in the end  I found out that I never reached the then-block due to a non-returned promise in the legacy library I was using.

And the moral of this story: ALWAYS RETURN YOUR PROMISE! :)